# cqlsh giving OperationTimedOut

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have a 3-3 node Cassandra cluster on 4-core 16GB Ram EC2 m4.xlarge instances spread across two regions in AWS (US and Singapore, each with replication factor of two with NetworkReplicationStrategy). 
When I try to connect to it using cqlsh, I get the following error

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':
>   OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection,
>   last_host=None',)})

I get the same error even if I execute from the node itself or through using the public IP.

Anyone has also experienced this before? Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please provide the command line you are using? PublicIP might be a problem with your security group definition. What worked fine for me was something like 'cqlsh $HOSTNAME'.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check whether java program corresponding to cassandra is running  or not. (ps -ef | grep cassandra).

If it is running then it might be the problem of setting listen_address. If you specify your ip here then you can not access it through localhost. So, you can check **cqlsh `<privateip>`**.